# Excel Formula to pull left of selected cell

Tags: excel

I am looking to pull the value from the left cell of the cell I selected. I have done the following:
step1)
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
End Sub

step2)
I am currently using this formula: =cell("contents") to show the value of the cell i selected.

step3)
Now I need to pull the value to left of the cell i selected. How can i accomplish this? I am stuck.Is it possible to merge =cell("contents") with =RC[-1]????

all i need is the cell value to the left of the cell I selected? Any suggestions?

Comment: The cell to the left of the selected cell is **Selection.Offset(0,-1)**

Comment: yup, using offset will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

in 2010:

```
    activecell.offset(columnoffset:=-1).value
```

should get it.

For example this shows the value of B6

```
    Range("C6").Select
    MsgBox (ActiveCell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Value)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a cell with a formula to display the value left of any cell I click on. e.g A1 has a formula to display value. if i click on C5, the value of B5(left) should show in A1. or if i click on D10, the value of C10 should show in A1.

Comment: now you are talking about something different, grabbing the value of the left offset cell , using it in the formula of the currently selected cell, then placing it always in A1?